# The usage of "all [noun] long".

Tags: phrase-usage, grammaticality, usage

We say: "John has been doing something **all day/week long."**

Is this a stock phrase with "week" and "day" only?

Can I say:

> I slept all weekend long

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

**All** can be used to describe the **entire** duration of time, most common are

> **all day long
>
>   all week long
>
>   all year long
>
>   all night long
>
>   all weekend long** *(the entire weekend)*
>   **all day long**

an exception is **all life long** which is usually expressed as **entire life** ***(long)*** or **life long**

> He lived in Europe his **entire life**
>   He is a **life long** follower of French Impressionism

Comment: You wouldn't use this construct for short times, like minutes or hours. "He held his breath all minute long." sounds wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much. So "I slept all weekend long" would be the same as "I slept all weekend"?